I'm trying to deploy firebase functions but getting error related to google app instance
Even though I have owner access(not a billing or administrator account) and have blaze subscription, I get this error when trying to deploy Cloud Functions to Firebase:

There was an issue deploying your functions. Verify that your project has a Google App Engine instance setup at https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine and try again. If this issue persists, please contact support.
!  functions: Upload Error: Request to https://cloudfunctions.googleapis.com/v2/projects/yotap-test/locations/us-central1/functions:generateUploadUrl had HTTP Error: 403, Write access to project 'yotap-test' was denied: please check billing account associated and retry

